# Check data from SELECT and then INSERT new values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So, I have some table with data, I need get a new table with new data based on old data and then insert them into temp table for the next processing.

But I have got some problem with my SQL

```
DECLARE @PGNPGE float,
            @PGHTTP400PCT float,
            @PGHTTP500PCT float,
            @PGSLPCT float,
            @PGTME float;

    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
        PViews int, 
        Http400 int, 
        Http500 int, 
        PTime int, 
        ExclSimul int, 
        DispSimul int, 
        SlowPages int, 
        AESWA int
    );

    IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ApplicationID] = @AppID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PGNPGE = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 6;
        SELECT @PGHTTP400PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 31;
        SELECT @PGHTTP500PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 12;
        SELECT @PGSLPCT = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 49;
        SELECT @PGTME = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 72;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PGNPGE = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 6;
        SELECT @PGHTTP400PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 31;
        SELECT @PGHTTP500PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 12;
        SELECT @PGSLPCT = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 49;
        SELECT @PGTME = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 72;
    END

    INSERT INTO @tempTable (
        PViews, 
        Http400, 
        Http500, 
        PTime, 
        ExclSimul, 
        DispSimul, 
        SlowPages, 
        AESWA )
    SELECT 
        [PViews] = CASE WHEN sel.[PGNPGE] < @PGNPGE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [Http400] = CASE WHEN sel.[PGHTTP400PCT] > @PGHTTP400PCT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        [Http500] = CASE WHEN sel.[PGHTTP500PCT] > @PGHTTP500PCT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        [PTime] = CASE WHEN sel.[PGTME] > @PGTME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        [ExclSimul] = CASE WHEN ([PViews] + [Http400] + [Http500] + [PTime]) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        [DispSimul] = CASE WHEN ([PViews] + [Http400] + [Http500] + [PTime]) > 1 THEN ([PViews] + [Http400] + [Http500] + [PTime]) ELSE 0 END, 
        [SlowPages] = CASE WHEN sel.[PGSLPCT] > @PGSLPCT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        [AESWA] = CASE WHEN [ExclSimul] >=1  THEN 0 ELSE [SlowPages] END
    FROM (SELECT [PGNPGE], [PGHTTP400PCT], [PGHTTP500PCT], [PGSLPCT], [PGTME]
            FROM [dbo].[TimeValue]
            WHERE [ApplicationID] = @AppID
            AND [Time] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo) sel;

SELECT * FROM @tempTable;
```

and errors where I'm adding new values

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
>   Invalid column name 'PViews'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
>   Invalid column name 'Http400'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
>   Invalid column name 'Http500'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
>   Invalid column name 'PTime'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'PViews'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'Http400'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'Http500'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'PTime'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'PViews'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'Http400'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'Http500'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
>   Invalid column name 'PTime'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   Invalid column name 'ExclSimul'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>   Invalid column name 'SlowPages'.

Comment: You can't refer to a table alias in the same `select` where it is defined.  You can use subqueries if you like, or just repeat the expression.

Comment: I thought it was possible to somehow get around

Comment: Yup.  That's just another way of assigning an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CTE to insert data in the table variable:

```
declare @PGNPGE float,
    @PGHTTP400PCT float,
    @PGHTTP500PCT float,
    @PGSLPCT float,
    @PGTME float;

declare @tempTable TABLE 
(
    PViews int, 
    Http400 int, 
    Http500 int, 
    PTime int, 
    ExclSimul int, 
    DispSimul int, 
    SlowPages int, 
    AESWA int
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ApplicationID] = @AppID)
BEGIN
    SELECT @PGNPGE = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 6;
    SELECT @PGHTTP400PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 31;
    SELECT @PGHTTP500PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 12;
    SELECT @PGSLPCT = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 49;
    SELECT @PGTME = Value FROM [ApplicationThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 72;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @PGNPGE = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 6;
    SELECT @PGHTTP400PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 31;
    SELECT @PGHTTP500PCT = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 12;
    SELECT @PGSLPCT = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 49;
    SELECT @PGTME = Value FROM [ApplicationTypeThreshold] WHERE [ThresholdID] = 72;
END

;with ThresholdCTE
as
(
    SELECT 
        case when sel.[PGNPGE] < @PGNPGE then 1 else 0 end as [PViews],
        case when sel.[PGHTTP400PCT] > @PGHTTP400PCT then 1 else 0 end as [Http400], 
        case when sel.[PGHTTP500PCT] > @PGHTTP500PCT then 1 else 0 end as [Http500], 
        case when sel.[PGTME] > @PGTME then 1 else 0 end as [PTime], 
        case when ([PViews] + [Http400] + [Http500] + [PTime]) >= 1 then 1  else 0 end as [ExclSimul], 
        case when ([PViews] + [Http400] + [Http500] + [PTime]) > 1 then ([PViews] + [Http400] + [Http500] + [PTime]) else 0 end as [DispSimul], 
        case when sel.[PGSLPCT] > @PGSLPCT then 1 else 0 end as [SlowPages], 
        case when [ExclSimul] >=1 then 0 else [SlowPages] end as [AESWA]
    from [dbo].[TimeValue]
    where [ApplicationID] = @AppID
          and [Time] between @DateFrom and @DateTo
)

insert into @tempTable 
(
    PViews, 
    Http400, 
    Http500, 
    PTime, 
    ExclSimul, 
    DispSimul, 
    SlowPages, 
    AESWA 
)
select
    PViews, 
    Http400, 
    Http500, 
    PTime, 
    ExclSimul, 
    DispSimul, 
    SlowPages, 
    AESWA 
from [ThresholdCTE]


SELECT * FROM @tempTable;
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'PViews' and else